# Who is the composer for DBFZ?

Tags: dragon-ball-fighterz

Who is the composer for Dragon Ball FighterZ?

This rules out Daisuke Ishiwatari: http://shoryuken.com/2017/07/18/shoryuken-interview-daisuke-ishiwatari-and-toshimichi-mori-from-arc-system-works/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking over the game credits, I found the composers are:

- Toshiyuki Kishi
- Hiromi Mizutani
- Kenji Katoh
- Reno

Answer (score -1):

Seems no author name can be found. Which can mean 2 things:

- The author wanted to be uncredited
- The music has been created by an in-house team, that didn't have a star name attached to it or a clear leader. (I personnaly think this is a high probability. It's rare studios in gaming, but also in cinema and TV, will credit a person in particular if nobody that worked on the soundtrack have a recognisable name)

Also, seems like there's a music pack coming that will feature music from the DB anime. So that might be why no composer has been credited; the music is just lifted from the anime itself (if you never heard them watching the anime, they might be using tracks that were created for the anime, but have gone unused.)

Comment: Playing the beta, the music wasn't from any version of the anime. It could be unused tracks, but I doubt that as generally those aren't designed to be looped within games.

Comment: Yeah, its just something I fell on while googling it. I'd say that if you want a defenitive answer, sit through the credits roll.